# opencv r6010 abort() has been called error in visual studio 2013

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2013

I have some code to draw a line between two points on an image which are selected by mouse, and then to display a histogram.
However, when I press `q` as required by code I get an error saying R6010 abort() has been called and saying VC++ run time error.

Please advise me how I can find this error.

```
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv\cv.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

struct Data_point 
{
    int  x;
    unsigned short int  y;
};

int PlotMeNow(unsigned short int *values, unsigned int nSamples)
{
    std::vector<Data_point> graph(nSamples);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nSamples; i++)
    {
        graph[i].x = i;
        graph[i].y = values[i];
    }

    cv::Size imageSize(5000, 500); // your window size
    cv::Mat image(imageSize, CV_8UC1);

    if (image.empty()) //check whether the image is valid or not
    {
        std::cout << "Error : Image cannot be created..!!" << std::endl;
        system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Good job : Image created successfully..!!" << std::endl;
    }

    // tru to do some ofesseting so the graph do not hide on x or y axis 
    Data_point dataOffset;

    dataOffset.x = 20;
    // we have to mirror the y axis!
    dataOffset.y = 5000;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<nSamples; ++i)
    {
        graph[i].x = (graph[i].x + dataOffset.x) * 3;
        graph[i].y = (graph[i].y + dataOffset.y) / 200;
    }

    // draw the samples
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i<nSamples - 1; ++i)
    {
        cv::Point2f p1;
        p1.x = graph[i].x;
        p1.y = graph[i].y;
        cv::Point2f p2;
        p2.x = graph[i + 1].x;
        p2.y = graph[i + 1].y;
        cv::line(image, p1, p2, 'r', 1, 4, 0);
    }

    cv::namedWindow("MyWindow1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window with the name "MyWindow"
    cv::imshow("MyWindow1", image); //display the image which is stored in the 'img' in the "MyWindow" window
    while (true)
    {
        char c = cv::waitKey(10);
        if (c == 'q')
            break;
    }
    destroyWindow("MyWindow1");
    destroyWindow("MyWindow"); //destroy the window with the name, "MyWindow"
    return 0;
}



void IterateLine(const Mat& image, vector<ushort>& linePixels, Point p2, Point p1, int* count1)
{
    LineIterator it(image, p2, p1, 8);

    for (int i = 0; i < it.count; i++, it++)
    {  
        linePixels.push_back(image.at<ushort>(it.pos()));   //doubt
    }

    *count1 = it.count;
}


//working line with mouse
void onMouse(int evt, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    if (evt == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
    {
        std::vector<cv::Point>* ptPtr = (std::vector<cv::Point>*)param;
        ptPtr->push_back(cv::Point(x, y));
    }
}


void drawline(Mat image, std::vector<Point>& points)
{
    cv::namedWindow("Output Window");
    cv::setMouseCallback("Output Window", onMouse, (void*)&points);

    int X1 = 0, Y1 = 0, X2 = 0, Y2 = 0;

    while (1)
    {
        cv::imshow("Output Window", image);

        if (points.size() > 1) //we have 2 points
        {
            for (auto it = points.begin(); it != points.end(); ++it)
            {
            }
            break;
        }
        waitKey(10);
    }


    //just for testing that we are getting pixel values 
    X1 = points[0].x;
    X2 = points[1].x;

    Y1 = points[0].y;
    Y2 = points[1].y;

    //   Draw a line 
    line(image, Point(X1, Y1), Point(X2, Y2), 'r', 2, 8);
    cv::imshow("Output Window", image);

    //exit image window 
    while (true)
    {
        char c = cv::waitKey(10);
        if (c == 'q')
            break;
    }
    destroyWindow("Output Window");
}


void show_histogram_image(Mat img1)
{
    int sbins = 65536;
    int histSize[] = { sbins };
    float sranges[] = { 0, 65536 };
    const float* ranges[] = { sranges };
    cv::MatND hist;
    int channels[] = { 0 };
    cv::calcHist(&img1, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), // do not use mask
            hist, 1, histSize, ranges,
            true, // the histogram is uniform
            false);

    double maxVal = 0;
    minMaxLoc(hist, 0, &maxVal, 0, 0);
    int xscale = 10;
    int yscale = 10;

    cv::Mat hist_image;
    hist_image = cv::Mat::zeros(65536, sbins*xscale, CV_16UC1);

    for int s = 0; s < sbins; s++)
    {
        float binVal = hist.at<float>(s, 0);
        int intensity = cvRound(binVal * 65535 / maxVal);

        rectangle(hist_image, cv::Point(s*xscale, hist_image.rows),
            cv::Point((s + 1)*xscale - 1, hist_image.rows - intensity),
            cv::Scalar::all(65535), 1);

    }


    imshow("Histogram", hist_image);
    waitKey(0);
}


int main()
{
    vector<Point> points1;
    vector<ushort>linePixels;

    Mat img = cvLoadImage("desert.jpg");

    if (img.empty()) //check whether the image is valid or not 
    {
        cout << "Error : Image cannot be read..!!" << endl;
        system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return -1;
    }
    //Draw the line 
    drawline(img, points1); 

    //now check the collected points
    Mat img1 = cvLoadImage("desert.jpg");

    if (img1.empty()) //check whether the image is valid or not 
    {
        cout << "Error : Image cannot be read..!!" << endl;
        system("pause"); //wait for a key press
        return -1;
    }

    int *t = new int;
    IterateLine( img1, linePixels, points1[1], points1[0], t );   
    PlotMeNow(&linePixels[0], t[0]);

    show_histogram_image(img);
    delete t;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: VS has a great debugger  - use it to step through your code. Also, format your code and eliminate all the superfluous stuff, Be clear in your question  -- it is not clear which waitKey the problem comes after. Lastly, why not `int t;  IterateLine(..., &t);`?

Comment: Problem is solved your reviews helped me thankyou

Comment: If my answer was helpful you should up-vote it :-). It might be helpful to others if you described what the solution is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *one* of the bad smells in your code:

```
void IterateLine(const Mat& image, vector<ushort>& linePixels, Point p2, Point p1, int* count1)
{
    ...
        linePixels.push_back(image.at<ushort>(it.pos()));   //doubt
```

Now `image` is a CV_8UC3 image (from `Mat img1 = cvLoadImage("desert.jpg");`, but you are accessing here like it is CV_16UC1, so what gets put in `linePixels` is garbage. This will almost certainly cause `PlotMeNow()` to draw outside its image and corrupt something, which is probably why your code is crashing.

Sine it is very unclear what your code is trying to do, I can't suggest what you should have here instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have just managed to do this, you only have to put "-1" to your loop limit:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < nSamples-1; i++)
{
    graph[i].x = i;
    graph[i].y = values[i];
}
```